# iPhone AES Rijndael 128 decryption

Tags: iphone, aes, decode, encryption

i have a problem:

I encrypt data, and encode it in base64..after, i send it to my page php and it decode and decrypt data. OK!

Now, if i encrypt and encode data in php and send it to my application, my app decode data and decrypt data, but the result is half of length of string. Look this:

PLAINTEXT: **xLxE9sY8vkBTGDpvz0DkLkejLSjuVhBq**

CHIPER FROM SERVER: **jp6gtdy/tf8mnQoeZCQjPuauq089eJvmns0DP4kvDzw=**

DECRYPT CHIPER SERVER IN MY APP: **xLxE9sY8vkBTGDpv**     <--- IT'S HALF!!!!

But if i encrypt the plaintext in my app, the result is different:

CHIPER FROM APP:    **jp6gtdy/tf8mnQoeZCQjPuauq089eJvmns0DP4kvDzzjd4QC2afnXreH/VpUo/Mw**

CHIPER FROM SERVER: **jp6gtdy/tf8mnQoeZCQjPuauq089eJvmns0DP4kvDzw=**

and decrypt is ok:

DECRYPT CHIPER APP: **xLxE9sY8vkBTGDpvz0DkLkejLSjuVhBq**

Now, i have used a online tool with the 2 chyper text..and the result is the same!! the plaintext!!! TRY!!! (http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/decrypt/) !?!?!?!

My function in my app is this:

```
+ (NSData*)decryptData:(NSData*)data key:(NSData*)key iv:(NSData*)iv;
{
    NSData* result = nil;

    // setup key
    unsigned char cKey[FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];
    bzero(cKey, sizeof(cKey));
    [key getBytes:cKey length:FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];

    // setup iv
    char cIv[FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
    bzero(cIv, FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE);
    if (iv) {
        [iv getBytes:cIv length:FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
    }

    // setup output buffer
    size_t bufferSize = [data length] + FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    // do decrypt
    size_t decryptedSize = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                          FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          cKey,
                                          FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE,
                                          cIv,
                                          [data bytes],
                                          [data length],
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &decryptedSize);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        result = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:decryptedSize];
    } else {
        free(buffer);
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] failed to decrypt| CCCryptoStatus: %d", cryptStatus);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This function first decode and after decrypt:

```
  + (NSString*)decryptBase64String:(NSString*)encryptedBase64String keyString:(NSString*)keyString
    {
        NSData* encryptedData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:encryptedBase64String];
        NSData* data = [self decryptData:encryptedData
                                     key:[keyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                      iv:nil];
        if (data) {
            return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
        } else {
            return nil;
        }
    }
```

Decode function:

```
+ (NSData *)dataFromBase64String:(NSString *)aString
{
    NSData *data = [aString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    size_t outputLength;
    void *outputBuffer = NewBase64Decode([data bytes], [data length], &outputLength);
    NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:outputBuffer length:outputLength];
    free(outputBuffer);
    return result;
}

void *NewBase64Decode(
    const char *inputBuffer,
    size_t length,
    size_t *outputLength)
{
    if (length == -1)
    {
        length = strlen(inputBuffer);
    }

    size_t outputBufferSize =
        ((length+BASE64_UNIT_SIZE-1) / BASE64_UNIT_SIZE) * BINARY_UNIT_SIZE;
    unsigned char *outputBuffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(outputBufferSize);

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;
    while (i < length)
    {
        //
        // Accumulate 4 valid characters (ignore everything else)
        //
        unsigned char accumulated[BASE64_UNIT_SIZE];
        size_t accumulateIndex = 0;
        while (i < length)
        {
            unsigned char decode = base64DecodeLookup[inputBuffer[i++]];
            if (decode != xx)
            {
                accumulated[accumulateIndex] = decode;
                accumulateIndex++;

                if (accumulateIndex == BASE64_UNIT_SIZE)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //
        // Store the 6 bits from each of the 4 characters as 3 bytes
        //
        // (Uses improved bounds checking suggested by Alexandre Colucci)
        //
        if(accumulateIndex >= 2)  
            outputBuffer[j] = (accumulated[0] << 2) | (accumulated[1] >> 4);  
        if(accumulateIndex >= 3)  
            outputBuffer[j + 1] = (accumulated[1] << 4) | (accumulated[2] >> 2);  
        if(accumulateIndex >= 4)  
            outputBuffer[j + 2] = (accumulated[2] << 6) | accumulated[3];
        j += accumulateIndex - 1;
    }

    if (outputLength)
    {
        *outputLength = j;
    }
    return outputBuffer;
}
```

Comment: There are two thing happening here, AES and Base64. Please show the entire code including the Base64 decode in your app's code. Php tends to do both in one step, objective-c used two distinct steps and there is no Base54 decode in the iOS frameworks so 3rd party Base64 code is needed.

Comment: Show the entire code including the Base64 decode and an NSLog of it. NSLog the data received from the server, data after Base64 decode (should be a NSData hex display) and after decryptData (should be a NSData hex display).

Comment: NSData hex displays please. `NSLog(@"data: %@", data);` and `NSLog(@"result: %@", result);`

Comment: The Base64 from the server does not look like it has padding, try without the kCCOptionPKCS7Padding option.

Comment: and what do i insert? i tryed with 0, but the result is the same..

Comment: Yes, use 0 for CCOptions. What is `FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM`?

Comment: Where is the code that converts the decrypt data to the string you show in the question.

Comment: Ok!!! I inserted 0 and work!!! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: But..Why if i encrypt and encode with padding, i haven't problem on server when i decode and decrypt?

Comment: You need to read the php docs. There is no padding so that is a php error if you specified padding. I have seen instances where padding is silently not added if the data is an exact multiple of the block size, this is incorrect. If the input is an exact multiple of the block size an extra block must be added to contain the padding length, in this case 0.

Comment: Any chance you could post a full Objective-c encrypt & decrypt example?

Comment: @MatteoGobbi:  Hi! I also need encryption and decryption implementation in one of my iOS Project. Please share encryption and decryption logics and implementation in iOS. I am unaware of cryptography in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is 32 bytes in length, this is two blocks in size. The Base64 is also 32 bytes in length so no padding was added, there is no space for padding so it is not PKCS7 padded, remove the kCCOptionPKCS7Padding  option.